# pyodbc.Error: Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, azure, pyodbc

I'm trying to access microsoft AZURE paid SQL database. I'm using the following

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=myserverhere,1433;Database=serverdb;Uid=myuidhere;Pwd={passhere};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
```

I've followed their installation instructions everytime I run the file  I get

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you connect to sql server from linux, you have to change the driver:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=myserverhere;PORT=1433;DATABASE=serverdb;UID=myuidhere;PWD={passhere};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
```

Comment: Yes, I've setup FreeTDS server finally now. However I'm running through loads of issues with it.

Comment: pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: FreeTDS is correct, I think your query string has issue, can you share your current using one? note my answer added one parameter `PORT=1433` based on the query in your question.

Comment: Got it. Silly me I add tcp: under my server hence it was throwing me error :) Thanks!